# Multiple choice custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i try to create a multiplichoice listview, but i just can select one. Here is my code:

Selector (multiselect_background.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey"/>
</selector>
```

ListView (list.xml):

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
/>
```

Layout (select_item.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/multiselect_background">
```

Somebody knows, why the multiselect isn't possible? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally made a custom ListView, with an array of ITEMS and an array of booleans the same size (initialized at false).

Each time a cell is clicked, it colors it and saves its state in the array of booleans (b = !b).

Worked great. I guess you got the idea, no code needed. If so, please tell.

Comment: Actually, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925892/android-how-do-i-highlight-a-row-in-listview