# Why is the wrong ListView item highlighted?

Tags: java, android, listview, selecteditem, listviewitem

I implemented a `ListView`, and the method `OnItemLongClick` to highlight the selected item, but when I select an item, if I scroll the `ListView`, I find that another item is highlighted.

I'm using this code:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
          public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
              arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
              return true;
          }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a header view for your ListView?

Comment: that's view recycling. don't store state in views. instead, keep something like a selected index, and update the background in the getView of your adapter

Comment: @njzk2 do you mean to use for example: list.getChildAt (pos).setBackround..etc?? Cause also that doesn't work, by the way I don't know how to update the background from the adapter :(

Comment: @pietv8x I use an xml file which xontains a textview and an imageview, I call that file when I devleare the adapter

Comment: Which kind of adapter are you using? Would you be overriding the BaseAdapter or using an ArrayAdapter?

Comment: absolutely not. never, ever are you to access list elements using `getChildAt`. In the `getView` set the background of the element you are working on, based on whether it is selected or not.

Comment: @Losin' Me I am using the arrayadapter

Comment: @njzk2 so if in OnItemLongClick I have to see if the element is selected and if so I can change the background,  and there would be no problem ?

Comment: Hey, try this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199381/3309883

Comment: Do not rely on the index of the item, instead change the item on the base list. The indices get recycled and the same indices would get assigned to another item on scroll. Find out the right item from your list based on the property and highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `android:listSelector` property instead of `onItemLongClick`